# svn permission issue - txn-current-lock: Permission denied

Tags: linux, svn, shell, permissions, permission-denied

I setup svn on my local system `/svn/repos/myproject` by following [this](http://www.botsko.net/blog/2007/05/17/installing-subversion-on-fedora-core/) tutorial. I'm able to view the repo in browser.

But when it try to import new project I couldn't through svn client ( rapid svn ) it shows following error:

```
Execute: Import
Error while performing action: 
Can't open file '/svn/repos/myproject/db/txn-current-lock': Permission denied
```

Svn directory permissions:

```
→ ls -l /svn
total 12
drwxrwxr-x 2 root   root 4096 Feb 15 12:09 permissions
drwxrwxr-x 4 apache apache 4096 Feb 15 12:09 repos
drwxrwxr-x 2 root   root 4096 Feb 15 12:09 users
```

Repo directory:

```
→ ls -l
total 8
drwxrwxr-x 3 root   root   4096 Feb 15 12:09 conf
drwxrwxr-x 7 apache apache 4096 Feb 15 12:09 myproject
```

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've given 777 permission to `repos` directory which solved this issue. But i got another issue like `Couldn't perform atomic initialization`.

I think this is due to incompatible sqlite version with subversion we're using, this can be solved by updating **svnadmin** command,

```
svnadmin create --pre-1.6-compatible --fs-type fsfs /svn/repos/myproject
```